# Why is react-nestable rendering [object Object] instead of expected JSX?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, conditional-rendering

I am trying to render custom JSX snippets based on the objects stored in an array in using react nestable. But instead of the JSX snippet, [object Object] gets rendered on the screen. Here is my code

```
//Top of the component file
import Nestable from "react-nestable"

const template = [
  {
    id: uuid(),
    type: "button1",
    text: "Next"
  },
  {
    id: uuid(),
    type: "button2",
    text: ["Back", "Next"]
  }
]

//Inside the component function
const [items, setItems] = useState(template)

const renderItems = ({ item }) => {
    switch (item.type) {
      case "button1":
        return (
          <tr key={item.id} style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }}>
            <td colSpan="2" style={{ padding: "16px" }}>
              <button
                contentEditable="true"
                style={{
                  border: "none",
                  outline: "none",
                  backgroundColor: "#2563eb",
                  borderRadius: "7px",
                  padding: "8px 12px",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  fontWeight: "500",
                  letterSpacing: "0.5px"
                }}
              >
                {item.text}
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        )
      case "button2":
        return (
          <tr key={item.id} style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }}>
            <td style={{ padding: "16px" }}>
              <button
                contentEditable="true"
                style={{
                  border: "none",
                  outline: "none",
                  backgroundColor: "#db2777",
                  borderRadius: "7px",
                  padding: "8px 12px",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  fontWeight: "500",
                  letterSpacing: "0.5px"
                }}
              >
                {item.text[0]}
              </button>
            </td>
            <td style={{ padding: "16px" }}>
              <button
                contentEditable="true"
                style={{
                  border: "none",
                  outline: "none",
                  backgroundColor: "#2563eb",
                  borderRadius: "7px",
                  padding: "8px 12px",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  fontWeight: "500",
                  letterSpacing: "0.5px"
                }}
              >
                {item.text[1]}
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        )
    }
  }

//Inside component return
<table style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}>
 <Nestable items={items} renderItems={renderItems} />
</table>
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

When I paste the snippets that I returned in the function renderItems directly instead of the  the snippet renders perfectly.

What I am expecting:[image]

I have tried removing the inline styles, reinstalling the packages but did not work. Alternative approaches are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code you need to change the key name that you are passing into Nestable component it's default API key name for renderItems is **renderItem** but your current key with *renderItems* 's' at last.

```html
 <Nestable items={items} renderItem={renderItems} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).